# Merge 2 dataframes and updating column values in R

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 data frames,

```
R1 <- c("15515","5156","65656","1566", "2857")
RC <- c("A","X","B","Z","A")
R2 <- c("515","5156.11-","415-","1455-","886")
df <- data.frame(R1,RC,R2)

R1 <- c("15515","8888","65656","1566")
R2 <- c("111","222","333","444")
R3 <- c("999","888","777","666")
df2 <- data.frame(R1,R2,R3)
```

I need to first left join df on R1,

Conditions to be achieved,

```
1. if df$R1 != df2$R1
  df$R2 <- df$R2  (As it is in df)
  
2. if df$R1 == df2$R1 & (df$RC == A | df$RC == B) then,
  df$R2 <- df2$R2
  
3. if df$R1 == df2$R1 & (df$RC != A | df$RC != B) then,
  df$R2 <- df2$R3
```

The output may look like

```
 R1        RC        R2
15515      A        111
5156       X        5156.11-
65656      B        333
1566       Z        666
2857       A        886
```

I tried executing below code,

```
df$R1[which(df$R1 == df2$R1) & which((df$RC == 'A' | df$RC == 'B'))] <- df2$R2[which(df$R1 == df2$R1) & which((df$RC == 'A' | df$RC == 'B'))]
df$R1[which(df$R1 == df2$R1) & which((df$RC != 'A' | df$RC != 'B'))] <- df2$R3[which(df$R1 == df2$R1) & which((df$RC != 'A' | df$RC != 'B'))]
```

But I lost condition 1 from this.

Your kind help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you are using a version <4.0.0 you should use the data.frame call with StringsAsFactors=FALSE. The RC column is otherwise handled as a factor and that might cause unwanted side effects later on.

Comment: I use Version 1.1.383 – © 2009-2017 RStudio, Inc. I believe the data is in Factors only since beginning. Ain't it will be fine?

Comment: `df` and `df2` do not have same number of rows. How do you compare them `df$R1 == df2$R1` ?

Comment: Hi @RonakShah I am not fully sure but, we can first left join (df) and then go for solving conditions one by one. will n't  it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `df` with `df2` on `R1` and apply conditions with `case_when` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'R1') %>%
  mutate(R2 = case_when(is.na(R2.y) ~ R2.x, 
                        RC %in% c('A', 'B') ~ R2.y, 
                        TRUE ~ R3)) %>%
  select(names(df))

#     R1 RC       R2
#1 15515  A      111
#2  5156  X 5156.11-
#3 65656  B      333
#4  1566  Z      666
#5  2857  A      886
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am getting NA in some R2 column,
     R1 RC       R2
1 15515  A     <NA>
2  5156  X 5156.11-
3 65656  B     <NA>
4  1566  Z     <NA>
5  2857  A      886

Comment: @Vin Please convert factor columns to characters first. The simple way in your example is `df <- data.frame(R1,RC,R2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` do the same for `df2`. Or if the dataframe is already created you can also use `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` to convert all columns to characters.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working on actual data. I am not sure why. At the end I am getting same values in R2 as it was in df (actual data is different), any other reason?

Comment: @Vin Did you assign the result back to new object? `df1 <- df %>% left_join(df2, by = 'R1')....` ?

Comment: Oops, Now it worked... Thanks a lot! but I had 485504 before left join, now I have 523692 records, though I don't have any NA/NULL/duplicates in join's linked column.

Comment: I think some `R1` values might be duplicates in either `df1` or `df2` which increases number of rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RonakShah, you are a true gem!

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe easier to do this with `ifelse`. Note that df and df2 have different nrows so there will be a warning:

```
df$R2 <- ifelse(df$R1 != df2$R1, df$R2,
  ifelse(df$R1 == df2$R1 & (df$RC == "A" | df$RC == "B"), df2$R2,
    ifelse(df$R1 == df2$R1 & (df$RC != "A" | df$RC != "B"), df2$R3, "X")
  )
)
```

Maybe you can leave out the last ifelse, which prints and "X" if none of your criteria are fullfilled.

Also im running R Version 3.6.1 and i get an error message if i dont use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Comment: I am getting error on this code,

Error in Ops.factor(df$R1, df2$R1) : level sets of factors are different
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length